# Favorite tag highlighting for just the tags

Tags: script

I really liked [the idea from Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238591/should-favorite-tag-highlighting-in-question-lists-be-changed) of highlighting the tags rather than the entire question - it was too overwhelming, so I created a userscript to do just this:

From:

[image: Before view]

To:

[image: After view]

(favorite tags are python, html, javascript in the pictures)

### How it works?

It gets the favorite tags from the sidebar of the websites. Because the API doesn't allow us to get the favorite tags of a user, this means it will only work on pages where the sidebar is present (although I think all pages with question lists have the bar :).

### Install

Tested on Google Chrome only, but I don't see why it shouldn't work on other userscript engines.

To install (on Chrome), download/save the file and drag into chrome://extensions. For other browsers, I have no idea ;p

I'd be happy for any feedback - I'm not a pro coder and there is definitely room for improvement :)

[The code](https://gist.github.com/shu8/415cd905568ad9667f46):

```
   // ==UserScript==
// @name         Interesting Questions alternate highlighting
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%B9%A7%D0%BD%CA%8A%C3%9F
// @version      0.2
// @description  Changes Stack Exchange websites 'favorite tags' highlighting to just the tag.
// @author       ṧнʊß
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
var userscript = function($) {
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
        
        if (window.location.href.indexOf('superuser') > -1) { //superuser
            var betterCSS = {
                backgroundColor: '#a1eaff',
                color: 'black'                
            };
        }
        else if (window.location.href.indexOf('stackoverflow') > -1) { //stackoverflow
            var betterCSS = {
                backgroundColor: '#ffefc6',
                borderWidth: '0'                
            };
        }
        else if (window.location.href.indexOf('.stackexchange.com') > -1) {
            if (window.location.href.indexOf('meta') === -1) { //beta sites
                var betterCSS = {
                backgroundColor: '#c3dafa',
                borderWidth: '0'                
                }; 
            }
        }

        var x = $("#interestingTags").text();
        var interesting = x.split(' ');
        interesting.pop(); //Because there's one extra value at the end

        

        $(".tagged-interesting > .summary > .tags > .post-tag").filter(function(index) {
            return interesting.indexOf($(this).text()) > -1;
        }).css(betterCSS);

        $(".tagged-interesting").removeClass("tagged-interesting");
    });
};

var el = document.createElement('script');
el.type = 'text/javascript';
el.text = '(' + userscript + ')(jQuery);';
document.head.appendChild(el);
```

### Change log

v. 0.2:

- Added Stackoverflow, Superuser, Beta sites specific colours, to more match their colour scheme.